# Java Generic super keyword

Tags: generics, super

I have the below program:

```
public void performGenerics() {
      List<? super Animal> testAnimal = new ArrayList<Animal>();
        testAnimal.add(new Dog());
    }
```

In the above code, Animal is the super class of Dog. My Question is, the meaning of super means, it should accept only Animal or Object class. Although Dog is the subclass of Animal, why it is letting to add the dog in the testAnimal collection ? I am quite confused on that. Can anybody let me know on this ?

Answer (score 0):

The exact meaning of it is this:

```
// This is a list of "something" whose superclass is definitely an animal
List<? super Animal> testAnimal = new ArrayList<Animal>();
```

It's kind of pointless. Better to write

```
// My list contains animals and any subclasses of them
// the new object gets its specialisation from the declaration of the
// type on the left (Java 7 onwards)
List<Animal> listOfAnimals = new ArrayList<>();
```

If you want your list to accept Objects as well as animals, then perhaps you shouldn't be using generics... or maybe you shouldn't be wanting to mix both Objects and Animals in a single list.

Comment: Thank You,  But I am not well-versed with java 7. I just want to see how the super keyword in basic generic work.  i.e, as per the java specification, it says that, when you use the super keyword, then it should accept anything that is super or equal to the  class. For example, if is say '? extends Animal', then it should accept Animal or object class. But I see that it also accepting "Dog" class which is a sub-class of Animal. Which shouldn't be accepted. Not able to get a clear idea on this. It would be great, if you could shed some light on this.

Comment: You're right. I was thinking of extends... why are you trying to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, a variable `List< ? super Animal >` is a list of some unknown element type `A` which *is a superclass of `Animal`*.  Therefore you can do with it anything that only needs to make that assumption.

Methods of that class which *accept* parameters of type `A`, such as `add()`, can take any argument which is of type `A` or any subclass of it.  `Dog`, being a subclass of `Animal`, must therefore also be a subclass of `A`.

Methods which *return* type `A`, such as `get()`, are quite useless, as the only thing we know about `A` is that it's a superclass of `Animal`.

So why would you ever use this construction?

Well, you wouldn't use it as presented.  Instead, consider the example of `SortedSet< T >`.  You can supply a `Comparator< ? super T >` to one of its constructors, because the only method of a comparator that is ever used is an acceptor method (`compare()`).

This means that you can create a sorted set of animals, a sorted set of canines, or a sorted set of dogs using the same comparator of animals.